# Jboss SecurityVaultException - Jdk7u191

Tags: java, jboss

Switched to JDK7u191 from JDK7u171. Seeing below error while brining up the Jboss.

```
05:05:51,804 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014612: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("core-service" => "vault")]): java.lang.RuntimeException: JBAS015804: Error initializing vault --  org.jboss.as.server.services.security.VaultReaderException: JBAS013313: Vault Reader Exception:
    at org.jboss.as.server.services.security.VaultAddHandler.performRuntime(VaultAddHandler.java:89) [jboss-as-server-7.4.3.Final-redhat-2-bz-1195283.jar:7.4.3.Final-redhat-3]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractAddStepHandler$1.execute(AbstractAddStepHandler.java:75) [jboss-as-controller-7.4.3.Final-redhat-2.jar:7.4.3.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:611) [jboss-as-controller-7.4.3.Final-redhat-2.jar:7.4.3.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.doCompleteStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:489) [jboss-as-controller-7.4.3.Final-redhat-2.jar:7.4.3.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.completeStepInternal(AbstractOperationContext.java:290) [jboss-as-controller-7.4.3.Final-redhat-2.jar:7.4.3.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:285) [jboss-as-controller-7.4.3.Final-redhat-2.jar:7.4.3.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.executeOperation(OperationContextImpl.java:1132) [jboss-as-controller-7.4.3.Final-redhat-2.jar:7.4.3.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.boot(ModelControllerImpl.java:322) [jboss-as-controller-7.4.3.Final-redhat-2.jar:7.4.3.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:292) [jboss-as-controller-7.4.3.Final-redhat-2.jar:7.4.3.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:346) [jboss-as-server-7.4.3.Final-redhat-2-bz-1195283.jar:7.4.3.Final-redhat-3]
    at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:321) [jboss-as-server-7.4.3.Final-redhat-2-bz-1195283.jar:7.4.3.Final-redhat-3]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:254) [jboss-as-controller-7.4.3.Final-redhat-2.jar:7.4.3.Final-redhat-2]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_191]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.services.security.VaultReaderException: JBAS013313: Vault Reader Exception:
    at org.jboss.as.security.vault.RuntimeVaultReader.createVault(RuntimeVaultReader.java:95) [jboss-as-security-7.4.3.Final-redhat-2.jar:7.4.3.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.server.services.security.VaultAddHandler.performRuntime(VaultAddHandler.java:87) [jboss-as-server-7.4.3.Final-redhat-2-bz-1195283.jar:7.4.3.Final-redhat-3]
    ... 12 more
Caused by: org.jboss.security.vault.SecurityVaultException: java.lang.RuntimeException: PBOX000140: Unable to get keystore (/instances/abc-test1/configuration/vault/vault.keystore)
    at org.picketbox.plugins.vault.PicketBoxSecurityVault.init(PicketBoxSecurityVault.java:210) [picketbox-4.0.19.SP10-redhat-1.jar:4.0.19.SP10-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.security.vault.RuntimeVaultReader.createVault(RuntimeVaultReader.java:93) [jboss-as-security-7.4.3.Final-redhat-2.jar:7.4.3.Final-redhat-2]
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: PBOX000140: Unable to get keystore (/instances/abc-test1/configuration/vault/vault.keystore)
    at org.picketbox.plugins.vault.PicketBoxSecurityVault.getKeyStore(PicketBoxSecurityVault.java:678) [picketbox-4.0.19.SP10-redhat-1.jar:4.0.19.SP10-redhat-1]
    at org.picketbox.plugins.vault.PicketBoxSecurityVault.init(PicketBoxSecurityVault.java:205) [picketbox-4.0.19.SP10-redhat-1.jar:4.0.19.SP10-redhat-1]
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Invalid secret key format
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.JceKeyStore.engineLoad(JceKeyStore.java:861) [sunjce_provider.jar:1.7.0_191]
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1357) [rt.jar:1.7.0_191]
    at org.picketbox.util.KeyStoreUtil.getKeyStore(KeyStoreUtil.java:201) [picketbox-4.0.19.SP10-redhat-1.jar:4.0.19.SP10-redhat-1]
    at org.picketbox.util.KeyStoreUtil.getKeyStore(KeyStoreUtil.java:151) [picketbox-4.0.19.SP10-redhat-1.jar:4.0.19.SP10-redhat-1]
    at org.picketbox.plugins.vault.PicketBoxSecurityVault.getKeyStore(PicketBoxSecurityVault.java:675) [picketbox-4.0.19.SP10-redhat-1.jar:4.0.19.SP10-redhat-1]
    ... 15 more

05:05:51,825 FATAL [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015957: Server boot has failed in an unrecoverable manner; exiting. See previous messages for details.
```

05:05:51,867 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015950: JBoss EAP 6.3.3.GA (AS 7.4.3.Final-redhat-2) stopped in 11ms

JBoss EAP 6.3.3.GA (AS 7.4.3.Final-redhat-2)

java version "1.7.0_191"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_191-b08)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.191-b08, mixed mode)

Comment: Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You should provide the [complete error message](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough). Have you read the release notes of the Java releases from the previous one to the new one installed to see if any changes could be impacting your installation? Is the keystore file actually there? Permissions?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe related to this change in [JDK 1.7.0u181](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/7-support-relnotes.html#R170_181) if you are using 3DES algorithms:

> security-libs/javax.net.ssl
> ➜3DES Cipher Suites Disabled
>
> To improve the strength of SSL/TLS connections, 3DES cipher suites
> have been disabled in SSL/TLS connections in the JDK via the
> jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms Security Property.
>
> JDK-8175075 (not public)

You can try the instructions from Oracle to re-enable a 3DES cipher:

> - On JDK 8 and earlier, edit the /lib/security/java.security file and remove 3DES_EDE_CBC
>   from the jdk.tls.legacyAlgorithms security property.
> - On JDK 9, edit the /conf/security/java.security file and remove 3DES_EDE_CBC from the jdk.tls.legacyAlgorithms security
>   property.
>
> For example, if the current value is:
>
> ```
> jdk.tls.legacyAlgorithms= \
>     K_NULL, C_NULL, M_NULL, \
>     DHE_DSS_EXPORT, DHE_RSA_EXPORT, DH_anon_EXPORT, DH_DSS_EXPORT, \
>     DH_RSA_EXPORT, RSA_EXPORT, \
>     DH_anon, ECDH_anon, \
>     RC4_128, RC4_40, DES_CBC, DES40_CBC, \
>     3DES_EDE_CBC
> ```
>
> The new value after removing 3DES_EDE_CBC would be:
>
> ```
> jdk.tls.legacyAlgorithms= \
>     K_NULL, C_NULL, M_NULL, \
>     DHE_DSS_EXPORT, DHE_RSA_EXPORT, DH_anon_EXPORT, DH_DSS_EXPORT, \
>     DH_RSA_EXPORT, RSA_EXPORT, \
>     DH_anon, ECDH_anon, \
>     RC4_128, RC4_40, DES_CBC, DES40_CBC
> ```